# Force git to not modify files in my working tree

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

I am working on a collaborative project and we're using github. There is a file called `user_info.csv` which is being tracked. There are commits that have been pushed by various people which modify it.

For testing, I would like to list my own users in it, and not have git update it even when commits indicate that it should. For example if I check out an older commit or do a pull, all files in my working tree that are tracked should be modified, except `user_info.csv`.

How can I have git not modify `user_info.csv` even when pulling/switching branches, and also leave it out of my index at all times?

I tried:

- `.gitignore`
- `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`
- `git update-index --assume-unchanged`

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself if the file actually belongs in version control?

If everyone is changing the file for their own personal use, then the file should be converted into a template that *is* tracked (e.g. `user_info.template` ) and all collaborators can create their own `user_info.csv` that is in the `exclude` or the `.gitignore`.

However, if the file is essential to the program and everyone *needs* it, then you should think about how you can do this differently:

1. create a new file and keep a copy of it outside of the project and copy it in each pull.
2. have a separate file with your changes and modify your testing files to use that file instead
3. create **fixtures** for your tests that don't include a file at all (of course depending on your testing environment )
4. When running your tests, create the new file with a script and delete it when you are done testing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file is tracked by Git it will always apply changes from other branches because *that is what it does*. Tracking content, you know. :)

Either untrack the file (careful, this will remove it from other people’s repositories, too, once they fetch that particular commit from you), or just move it away, update, and move it back again.

Comment: how do I untrack the file for only me?

Comment: By untracking (aka deleting) it from a local branch but then you will likely get conflicts every time you fetch an update from somebody else.